# how to reverse a number using array in java?

Tags: java

I am writing a code to reverse a number entered by a user using java. I am using an array for this purpose. The problem that I am facing is in returning the array when I call my method in the main function.

[image]

Comment: Don't post an image. There is a way you can add code. Please edit your question with the actual code.

Comment: It's easier if you treat it as a String.

Comment: looking at the code it looks like your return type needs to be [] like `public int[] getreverse(int a)`.

Comment: Why is posting text as image bad: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand that you want to reverse an array... so, for that you can use **[ArrayUtils.reverse](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/ArrayUtils.html#reverse(int[]))**

```
ArrayUtils.reverse(int[] array)
```

For example, you can do:

```
public static void main(String[] arg){
    int[] arr = { 1,2,3,4,5,6};
    ArrayUtils.reverse(arr);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
    // Prints: [6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
}
```

However, if you want to code the reverse by yourself, if you check the source code of ArrayUtils.reverse, you can find how Apache guys did it. Here the implementation:

```
public static void reverse(int[] array) {
    if (array == null) {
        return;
    }
    int i = 0;
    int j = array.length - 1;
    int tmp;
    while (j > i) {
        tmp = array[j];
        array[j] = array[i];
        array[i] = tmp;
        j--;
        i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, everyone for the inputs, it really helped in correcting my programme. I am new to this forum and all I can say is that it is really amazing and helpful.

Comment: Hi @PranavTyagi, if some of the answers solved your question don't forget to mark your question as resolved by accepting an answer

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways of doing it. Depends if you want to use Java Builtin methods or not. Here is my part:

1. Reverse a int array using ListIterator:

   ```
   public class ReverseAListWithoutInbuiltMethods {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
   int[] arr={12, 4, 34, 7, 78,33, 20};
   display(arr);
   int[] rev=reverse(arr);

   display(rev);
   }
   private static void display(int[] arr){

   for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
       System.out.print(" "+arr[i]);
   }
   System.out.println("");
   }
   private static  int[] reverse(int[] arr){
   List<Integer> list=new ArrayList<Integer>();

   for(int a:arr){
       list.add(a);
   }
   int[] rev=new int[arr.length];


   int j=0;

   ListIterator<Integer> listI=list.listIterator(arr.length);
   while(listI.hasPrevious()){
       rev[j]=listI.previous();

       j++;
   }
   return rev;
   }
   }
   ```
2. Reverse by for loop only:

   ```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
   /* create a new string */
   StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder("GeeksQuiz");
   System.out.println(" ************* REVERSED STRING IS **************");

   char[] c2=reverseForLoop(s);
   for (int i = 0; i < c2.length; i++) {
       System.out.print(c2[i]);
   }

   }
   private static char[] reverseForLoop(StringBuilder sb) {
   char[] str = sb.toString().toCharArray();
   int n = str.length;

   char[] charNew = new char[n];
   int j = 0;
   for (int i = n - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
       charNew[j] = str[i];
       j++;
   }
   return charNew;
   }
   ```
3. Reverse using swap method:

   ```
   private static char[] reverse2(StringBuffer sb) {
   char[] str=sb.toString().toCharArray();
           int n = str.length;
   for (int i = 0; i < n / 2; i++) {

       swap(str, i, n - 1 - i);
   }
   return str;
   }

   private static void swap(char[] charA, int a, int b) {
   char temp = charA[a];
   charA[a] = charA[b];
   charA[b] = temp;
   }
   ```
4. Reverse String using Stack implementation:

   ```
   public class StackForStringReverse {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
     /*create a new string */
   StringBuffer s= new StringBuffer("GeeksQuiz"); 

   /*call reverse method*/ 
   reverse(s); 

   /*print the reversed string*/ 
   System.out.println("Reversed string is " + s); 
   }
       private static void reverse(StringBuffer str) {
   int n=str.length();
   MyStack obj=new MyStack(n);
   // Push all characters of string  
   // to stack 
   int i; 
   for (i = 0; i < n; i++) 
   obj.push(str.charAt(i)); 

   // Pop all characters of string and put them back to str 
   for (i = 0; i < n; i++) 
   {  
       char ch = obj.pop(); 
       str.setCharAt(i,ch); 
   } 
   }
   }

   class MyStack{
       int size;
       char[] a;
       int top;
       public MyStack(int n) {
       top=-1;
       size=n;
       a=new char[size];//{'1','f','f','f'};

   }
   public boolean isEmpty() {
   return top<0;
   }
   /**
    * Insert data into Stack if it's not full*/
       public void push(char c) throws IllegalArgumentException{
       if(top>=size) {
       throw new IllegalArgumentException("Stack overflow.");
       }
   a[++top]=c;

   }
   public char pop() {
   if(top<0) {
       throw new IllegalArgumentException("Stack underflow.");
   } 
         char x=a[top--];
   return x;

   }
   public void clear() {
   while(top>0) {
       top--;
       size=top;
   }
   }
   /**
    * Display the data inserted */
       public void display() {
   for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++) 
   {
   System.out.print(a[i]);
   }
   System.out.println("");
   }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using StringBuilder :

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println(getReverse(s.nextInt()));
    }

    public static int getReverse(int a){
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append(String.valueOf(a));
        sb = sb.reverse();
        return Integer.parseInt(sb.reverse().toString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[StringBuilder can do reversals.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#reverse())

```
String reverseNumber(Number n) {
    String numStr = n.toString();
    StringBuilder reverser = new StringBuilder(numStr);
    reverser.reverse();
    return reverser.toString();
}
```

Obviously there are some gaps here for particular cases (e.g. negative numbers) but I'll leave that for you to solve. This should serve as a good starting point.

Answer (score 0):

Java is powerful, but complicated.

Here is a oneliner for it.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int n = 123; 
    int reversed_n = (int) Integer.valueOf( // 5.) cast back to an int. 
        new StringBuilder(
            Integer.toString(n)             // 1.) Make the integer a String. 
        )                                   // 2.) load that string to a String builder.
            .reverse()                      // 3.) reverse the string.
                .toString()));              // 4.) go back to a string.
}
```

Comment: What can I say -- I'm not a fan of explicit primitive to object casts. 
I like to be explicit.

Comment: Ok, that happens. I now know what you mean :).

Answer (score 0):

Tried my hand at a relatively well-documented, external library and array-free solution. Hope it helps!

```
int reverseNumber(int inputNum)
{
    String numString = Integer.toString(inputNum);
    int numLength = numString.length();

    int finalReversedNumber = 0;

    /*
     * Goes through the input number backwards, and adds the digit (with it's new value) to the final number.
     *  This is accomplished by multiplying the current number by 10 to the power of the index i, which corresponds
     *  to the current digit value of the number.
     * i the index counter, goes from the length of the input number (not inclusive) to 0 (inclusive)
     */
    for(int i=numLength-1; i>=0; i--)
    { 
        int currentNum = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(numString.charAt(i)));
        int valueInFinalNum = currentNum * (int)Math.pow(10, i); // i.e. a 5 in the thousands digit is actually 5000
        finalReversedNumber += valueInFinalNum;
    }

    return finalReversedNumber;
}
```